# Need to verify coding syntax for empty reult in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the piece of code I am having trouble with as far as I know it should be working but it is as if the if statement is not there.

$payloadObj->data is supplied in the call and contains a unique number used for identification

```
        $limit="";
        $order=" ORDER BY rmtID";
        $where=" WHERE udid = '".$data."'";
        $data=$payloadObj->data;
        $now = date("o-m-d H:i:s");
        $query00="SELECT DISTINCT udid FROM rmtCustomer".$where; 
        $result00 = mysql_query($query00)
            or die("Query failed -".$query00);
        //$items=mysql_num_rows($result00);
        if ($result00) {
            if (mysql_num_rows($result00) == 0) {
            //if(!$items){
                $query11="INSERT INTO rmtCustomer (rmtCustomerID, udid, date) VALUES ('', '".$data."', '".$now."')";
                $result11 = mysql_query($query11)
                    or die("Query failed -".$query11);  
                $query22="INSERT INTO rmtSales (rmtSalesID, udid, productCount, date) VALUES ('', '".$data."', '9', '".$now."')";
                $result22 = mysql_query($query22)
                    or die("Query failed -".$query22);  
            }
        }

        $query="SELECT rmtTitle as product FROM rmtData".$order.$limit;
        $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Query failed -".$query);        
        $rows=array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
```

I use variables $limit, $order, and $where to finish the queries since I have several of them it made it easier. They have been checked out and they are not an issue at all.

What the desired affect is to run the first query to check for a new customer if NO RECORD is found this is a new customer and then I want to run the queries in the if statement to add them to the customer table and to the sales table and then to continue with the remainder of the queries. If there is a record in the first result then the customer exists and I want to skip the insertion queries and move directly to the rest of the queries.

This example shows a few attempts so far the two lines commented out were my first attempts but got the same result.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. $data is initialized (line 4) after it being used (line 3). Shouldn't this be the other way around?
2. If udid is a primary key or unique index, you can simply run the insert and catch a "duplicate" error. This will improve your performance, since you don't need the first "select" query. Note: this will increase the next udid in case it is an auto-incremented field, even if the insert fails.
3. you say the "statement is not there", and I'm not really sure what that means..

Comment: OH SH%#@* I must be tired I did not even catch item 1 I apologize for taking up your time with such a simple error on my part. I thank you for your time